# Get values from collection in one module into combobox in userform

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a worksheet with data in column 'EGM'. My code saves values from this column in the collection. 
If there is only one value in the collection, then variable sSelectedEGM is equal to this value.
But if there is more than one values, a user should has possibility to choose only one value (I wanted to do this in the combobox) and save selected item into variable sSelectedEGM.

My problem is, that I can't get values from this collection into userform.
When my code go into useform, the error "Type mismatch" appear. My code in worksheet:

```
Public sSelectedEGM As String
Public vElement As Variant
Public cEGMList As New VBA.Collection

Sub kolekcjaproba()

' ===================================
'   LOOP THROUGH EGMS AND WRITE THEM INTO COLLECTION
' ===================================

Dim iOpenedFileFirstEGMRow As Integer
Dim iOpenedFileLastEGMRow As Integer
Dim iOpenedFileEGMColumn As Integer
Dim iOpenedFileEGMRow As Integer
Dim sOpenedFileEGMName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)


iOpenedFileFirstEGMRow = Cells.Find("EGM").Offset(1, 0).Row
iOpenedFileLastEGMRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, iOpenedFileFirstEGMRow).End(xlUp).Row
iOpenedFileEGMColumn = Cells.Find("EGM").Column

For iOpenedFileEGMRow = iOpenedFileFirstEGMRow To iOpenedFileLastEGMRow
    sOpenedFileEGMName = Cells(iOpenedFileEGMRow, iOpenedFileEGMColumn).Value
    For Each vElement In cEGMList
        If vElement = sOpenedFileEGMName Then
            GoTo NextEGM
        End If
    Next vElement
    cEGMList.Add sOpenedFileEGMName
NextEGM:
Next

If cEGMList.Count = 1 Then
    sSelectedEGM = cEGMList.Item(1)
ElseIf cEGMList.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No EGM found"
Else
    Load UserForm1

    UserForm1.Show
End If

End Sub
```

And my code in a userform (There is only a combobox on it)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    For Each vElement In cEGMList
        UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem vElement
    Next vElement

End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If ComboBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        sSelectedEGM = ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you don't need to use this on a Mac, I'd use a `Scripting.Dictionary` rather than a `Collection` - you can then simply assign its `Keys` property to the `List` property of the control.

Comment: Why not simply declare `Public cEGMList As Collection`?

Comment: I declared it like that but found also declaration like that. So i was trying to change everything what could be wrong :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to declare cEGMList and sSelectedEGM in a standard module as public and not in a worksheet module.

Or even better: create a property on the form for the collection and for the returned values. It's always better to avoid global vars wherever possible.

This is a simplified example. In the form you can define properties and methods like that:

```
Option Explicit

Public TestProperty As Integer

Public Sub TestMethod()
    MsgBox (TestProperty)
End Sub

Public Function TestMethodWithReturn() As Integer
    TestMethodWithReturn = TestProperty * 2
End Function
```

outside the form you can then use this as a normal property/method of the form:

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim retValue As Integer

    UserForm1.TestProperty = 123
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
    UserForm1.TestMethod

    retValue = UserForm1.TestMethodWithReturn
    Debug.Print retValue
End Sub
```

Comment: Ohh, it works! I was fighting with that for about 2 hours, didn't know it can't be in a worksheet. Thank you very much! I've never done something like create a property. Can you tell me more details about it?

Comment: have added an example for that to my answer